# Grails export plugin don't download any file

Tags: grails, export, grails-plugin

I want to use grails export plugin to get my Domain classes exportables into xls and csv files.

In my main layout named **front.gsp**, I did that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
        <g:layoutHead />
    </head>
    <body>
        <sec:ifLoggedIn>
        <r:require module="export"/>
        <export:formats formats="['csv', 'excel', 'ods', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'xml']" action="exportTest" />
        ...
        <g:layoutBody />
        <r:layoutResources/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'jquery.min.js')}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'bootstrap.min.js')}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'application.js')}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Into my **DomainClassController.groovy** I did that :

```
def exportTest() {
        if(!params.max) params.max = 10

        if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){
            response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format] response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=contacts.${params.extension}")

            exportService.export(
                params.format,
                response.outputStream,
                ContactDTO.list(params),
                [:],
                [:])
            [contactDTOInstanceList: ContactDTO.list( params )]
        }
    }
```

I also create a view named **exportTest.gsp** into my view folder of my controller, just empty file to temporarely solve 404 issue.

I did not have any error messages but when I'm clicking on any export button, I'm redirecting to my page **exportTest.gsp** and ***no file is downloaded***

How can I get a downloaded file using grails export plugin ? I follow the user guide, don't have any errors (solved) but no file is created ?

Thanks for reading !

Snite

**EDIT :** I just see that, when clicking on export link, the generated url is :

```
http://localhost:8080/site/controller/action?format=excel&extension=xls
```

But strangely, when making a "println params" into my controller, output is :

```
[extension:xls, action:exportTest, format:null, controller:contactDTO, max:10]
```

params.format is null BUT set into url ?!!!

Change url like that (and adapting controller code) :

```
http://localhost:8080/site/controller/action?formatD=excel&extension=xls
```

Give me the following error :

```
Firefox ne peut trouver le fichier à l'adresse http://localhost:8080/site/controller/action?formatd=excel&extension=xls.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is the params.format is getting confused with Grails content negotiation  format in parameter. The export tag seems to generate that format, unless that gets fixed you can create a link to your `exportTest` and pass the format you want under lets say exportFormat variable name. On your controller use exportFormat instead of format.

Also make sure that `ContactDTO.list(params)` is returning some values. Another point is make sure you have defined the content types in you config as it says in the export plugin  [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/export)

So you might need to create a link like this:

```
<a class="csv" href="/testData/loader/exportTest?exportFormat=csv&extension=csv"> 
  CSV 
</a>
```

In your controller :

```
def exportTest() {
        if(!params.max) params.max = 10

        if(params?.exportFormat && params.exportFormat != "html"){
            response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.exportFormat] 
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=contacts.${params.extension}")

            exportService.export(
                params.exportFormat,
                response.outputStream,
                ContactDTO.list(),
                [:],
                [:])
            [ContactDTO: ContactDTO.list( params )]
        }
    }
```

Comment: It was the point, I tested yesterday renaming params.format to params.formatt and it solve my problem. Thanks for explanations and your time !

Comment: I've forked (https://github.com/lrkwz/grails-export) and issued a pull request in order to fix this (https://github.com/nwwells/grails-export/pull/7)

Answer (score 0):

I did some by passing through this way

```
params.format=params.extension<br/>
        if(params.format=='xls') {
            params.format='excel'
        }
```

**Explanation**: As the `params.format` is `null`, I did a system print for extension, And I remark that the extension is the same as format for all extension except *xls*. So if *xls* I the format must be '*excel*' for *excel* exporting. This is why. In my cas it works fine for *csv*, *excel*, *pdf* and *xml*. Not tested with *ODD* etc..

Answer (score 0):

I am using export plugin version 2.0.0 with Grails 3. As per the internal implementation in Plugin's ExportTagLib.groovy the argument format has been renamed to avoid conflict with grails 3

ExportTagLib.groovy

```
Map params = [f: format, extension: extension] + parameters
```

Using params.f will work fine for now. Sample code.

```
        if (params.f && params.f != "html") {
        response.contentType = Holders.config.grails.mime.types[params.f]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${message(code: 'dpInvoice.exportBillFacilitator.filename', default: 'exportBillFacilitator')}.${params.extension}")
        exportService.export(params.f, response.outputStream, results, fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
    }
```