# Grails 2.3.x: get the value of URL parameters

Tags: url, grails, parameters

Given the URL

```
  http://localhost:9000/Estrategia/book/index?format=excel&extension=xls
```

I want to get the format value (in this case is excel)

In the controller:

`println params.format

[Grails docs reference](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/params.html)

But `params.format` is always null, any idea?

*Grails 2.3.5*

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class BookController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def exportService // Export service provided by Export plugin
    def grailsApplication  //inject GrailsApplication

   def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

    if(!params.max) 
    params.max = 10

    println params?.format
    [ bookInstanceList: Book.list( params ) ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your controller to question?

Comment: Where is `foo`? How is `/hello?foo=bar` mapped to this controller? were you referring to `params?.format`? What is the actual url you are trying to hit? *A problem well stated is a problem half solved* - I think you would agree to that. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are one of the luckiest victim of convention over configuration. ;)

An entry with key `format` is added to `params` as referred by default url mapping which represents the type of response that is expected (generally, whether xml/json) will be also be used for content negotiation which means, as an example, if you use:

```
http://localhost:9000/Estrategia/book/index.xml
//params -- [action:index, format:xml, controller:book]

http://localhost:9000/Estrategia/book/index.json
//params -- [action:index, format:json, controller:book]

http://localhost:9000/Estrategia/book/index.json?format=excel&extension=xls
//params -- [action:index, format:json, extension:xls, controller:book]

http://localhost:9000/Estrategia/book/index?format=excel&extension=xls
//params -- [action:index, format:null, extension:xls, controller:book]
```

`format` gets populated by the type of content you are asking for. Which also means, a request parameter with name `format` will get overridden and will be lost.

You can rename the request parameter to something other than `format` then it should be available in controller like `param.blah` if request parameter has `blah=excel`.

OR

modify url mapping and remove the optional `(.$format)?` if not required:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
     constraints {
         // apply constraints here
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your patience and very good explained answers. This seems weird to me, because I was using a Grails Plugin [Grails Export plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export)

Comment: Yes I see that `params.format` is used in the plugin. Plugin is too old. Right now, if possible modify the mapping, I would work on a PR for the plugin to adapt to newer versions of Grails.

Comment: Another StackOverflow page that could be of interest for anybody: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961339/grails-export-plugin-dont-download-any-file

Comment: LOL. It is [fixed in export plugin version 1.5](https://github.com/nwwells/grails-export/issues/5). Upgrade the plugin and use `exportFormat` instead of `format`. From the fix, I see a [SO answer related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961339/grails-export-plugin-dont-download-any-file/19970759#19970759).

Comment: Worth upgrading the README file in github with those changes and refer the github repo from the plugin page.

Comment: @Alberici Also note the PR is not merged yet.

Comment: in this case I could also do a: "renaming params.format to params.formatt" [the other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961339/grails-export-plugin-dont-download-any-file), for doing that renaming I need to enter to the plugin taglib and make the rename there right?

Answer (score 0):

since `format` is  token by the Grails platform ,  find below Another method to fix this problem via adding  `mapExtensionFormat` varaible :

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
static mapExtensionFormat=['pdf':'pdf','xls':'excel','csv':'csv','rtf':'rtf']
def exportService // Export service provided by Export plugin
def grailsApplication  //inject GrailsApplication
```

Then :

```
   def index(Integer max) {
        // ...
        String format=mapExtensionFormat[params?.extension]

  }
```