# Can't get params from url on Grails application

Tags: grails

I'm trying to get parameters from the url using param in a controller.  My url is: .../index?format=json

I've tried to get the params from the following two methods:

```
def format = params.format
def parameters = getParams()
```

The below is what I get in the debug results:

[image: screenshot]

My question is why the format value isn't coming through in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format parameter gets populated by the type of content you are asking for (JSON, XML, etc). So, a request parameter called format will get overridden.

See here for more details: [Grails 2.3.x: get the value of URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882691/grails-2-3-x-get-the-value-of-url-parameters)

Comment: Got it. This works if I change the request to /index.json rather than requesting the format through a variable.  I didn't realize format was a reserved name.

Comment: Ordinarily this would be the part where you accept this as the correct answer