# Grails Export Plugin Not Download

Tags: grails, export-to-excel, grails-plugin

I first tried this: [Grails export plugin don't download any file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961339/grails-export-plugin-dont-download-any-file), but it resulted nothing.

My **Controller**

```
// Export service provided by Export plugin 
def exportService
def grailsApplication  //inject GrailsApplication 

...other code...

def index = {
    if(!params.max)
        params.max = 10
    log.debug("Azienda is ${Azienda} or type ${Azienda.class}")
    if(params?.format && params.format != "html") {
        response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=aziende.${params.extension}")
        exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, Azienda.list(params), [:], [:])
    }
    [ aziendaList: Azienda.list( params ), filterParams: FilterPaneUtils.extractFilterParams(params) ]
}
```

My **index.gsp**

```
<r:require module="export"/>
...other code...
<export:formats />
```

My url link is this, `azienda/index?format=excel&extension=xls`. I tried to change format with other variable; something like this, `azienda/index?formatD=excel&extension=xls`.
And I changed my controller in this way:

```
if(params?.formatD && params.formatD != "html") {
    response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.formatD]
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=aziende.${params.extension}")
    exportService.export(params.formatD, response.outputStream, Azienda.list(params), [:], [:])
}
```

But, I got a `404 Page Not Found`.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. However on Stack Overflow, we don't use the title for this - we add an answer and click the tick mark. It is acceptable to self-answer here if you wish, and is encouraged if you think it is general enough that it will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
compile ":export:1.5"
```

line in your project `BuildConfig.groovy` file under plugins block and restart application.

Comment: compile ":export:1.6" i added this

Comment: you can use according to your version,.and make sure you have an active internet connection to download that plugin

Comment: i've got Grails-2.3.7

Comment: I solved. I discovered that if there ins't any row the plugin get error

Comment: do you know any solution for this? to avoid the page not found error?